# Phonegap: config.xml file only processing last uses-feature block

Tags: android, phonegap

I have an ios/android app built using cordova (cli-8.0.0) on the Adobe Phonegap Build platform.

My app uses gps and compass. I need to make the compass a required feature, and the location a not required, but stated feature.

So I tried this in the config.xml using 'uses-feature', but in the generated Android.manifest file, only the compass one is output. Swapping the order of the two uses-feature sections in the config.xml makes the location the only one output in the manifest.

What am I doing wrong??

Chris

```xml
<!--Android config overrides-->
<edit-config target="/manifest/uses-feature" file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="add" platform="android">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="/manifest/uses-feature" file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="add" platform="android">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="true"/>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: I tried using mode="add" rather than mode="merge", but when compiling, phone gap build gives :

`/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:25: AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-feature> found.
    
/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:28: AAPT: error: unknown element <uses-feature> found.
`

I don't get these errors when using merge. I figured that add would be most appropriate, but for some reason throws this error, and I've not been able to get to the bottom of it yet.

Answer (score 0):

mode="add" is right, but it also needed the target changing to "/manifest" not "/manifest/uses-feature".

Built ok, checked the manifest file and both entries are in there!